# Checking if preceding has particular type/Value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XML like the following

```
    <ARTICLE type="newspaper" segment="entertainment">
    <Price type="tax">$2</Price>
    </ARTICLE>
    <ARTICLE type="newspaper" segment="political">
    <Price type="tax">$1</Price>
    </ARTICLE>
```

Now what I am trying to do is to delete Price (block)  only when the immediate top element is ARTICLE and has segment="entertainment"

I have tried the following way , but it deletes both the  blocks

```
<xsl:template match="Price[@type='tax'] ">
<xsl:if test="preceding::ARTICLE[1]/attribute(segment)='entertainment'">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

need help on this . I have to delete price block only when segment is "entertainment" in immediate upper ARTICLE.

Comment: You can't use the `preceding` axis to select parents/ancestors- from the `Price` element, you're still within the `ARTICLE` element, therefore it doesn't precede it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell why your template isn't working without more context (like a well-formed sample XML).

This should work though:

```
<xsl:template match="Price[@type='tax' and parent::ARTICLE[@segment='entertainment']]"/>
```

If you still want the text of `Price`, add the `xsl:apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:template match="Price[@type='tax' and parent::ARTICLE[@segment='entertainment']]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try this:**

```
  <xsl:template match="Price[@type='tax'] ">
    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::ARTICLE[1]/attribute(segment)='entertainment'">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Just use the template:

```
<xsl:template match="ARTICLE[@segment='entertainment']/Price" />
```

This matches precisely the `price` element you're looking for, and outputs nothing in it's place.